# Transparency failure in swing components

Tags: java, swing, transparency, jcombobox

i've been having a problem with the transparency of a JCombobox, using Color(p,p,p,p). once i click on it, all the options displayed seem to be selected by the cursor when its only on one of them. and sometimes other buttons appear behind de transparency component, but they're not behind it.

The transparency really works, but i dont want it to seem bugged, i've been trying to use the paintComponents() method with the fill rect, and it worked only for the jcombobox when its options are not displayed, it seem perfect and not bugged, but once i display the options of the combobox, these seem to be all selected and with shadows of other components behind them. is there any way to get the displayed component of the jcombobox which contains the options, and set a not transparent background or something to solve this problem?

here is the code of the Panel where i have 3 buttons with MyComboBox, and a test Class:

```
//========================== MYCOMBOBOX CLASS ===========================

package views;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JComboBox;

import models.EnumModels;

public class MyComboBox<E> extends JComboBox<E> {

    public MyComboBox () {
        setOpaque(false);
        setBackground(new Color(18, 10, 44, 100));
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        g.setColor( getBackground() );
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        super.paintComponent(g);
    }
}
//======================= PANEL WITH MYCOMBOBOX ====================


package views;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import controller.Actions;
import controller.EventsController;
import models.EnumModels;

public class CentralPanel extends JPanel{

    MyButton info, add, recent, modelFilter;

    boolean bool;

    JTextField modelField;

    MyComboBox<EnumModels> modelsBox;

    public CentralPanel() {
        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        setSize(600,845);
        setOpaque(false);
        setBackground(new Color(18, 10, 44, 100));
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.decode("#E80909"), 4, true));

        JPanel infoPanel = new JPanel();
        infoPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        infoPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(100, 65, 0, 65));
        JPanel addPanel = new JPanel();
        addPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        addPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(100, 65, 0, 65));
        JPanel recentPanel = new JPanel();
        recentPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        recentPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(100, 65, 0, 65));
        JPanel modelFilterPanel = new JPanel();
        modelFilterPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        modelFilterPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(100, 65, 65, 65));


        info = new MyButton();
        info.setFont(new Font("Unispace", Font.BOLD, 24));
        info.setForeground(Color.decode("#E80909"));
        info.setText("Información de Vehículos");
        add = new MyButton();
        add.setFont(new Font("Unispace", Font.BOLD, 24));
        add.setForeground(Color.decode("#E80909"));
        add.setText("Agregar Vehículo");
        recent = new MyButton();
        recent.setFont(new Font("Unispace", Font.BOLD, 24));
        recent.setForeground(Color.decode("#E80909"));
        recent.setText("Vehículos Recientes");
        modelFilter = new MyButton();
        modelFilter.setFont(new Font("Unispace", Font.BOLD, 24));
        modelFilter.setForeground(Color.decode("#E80909"));
        modelFilter.setText("Filtro de Modelo");

        modelsBox = new MyComboBox<>();
        DefaultComboBoxModel model = new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(EnumModels.values());

        modelsBox.setModel(model);
//      modelsBox.setBackground(new Color(18, 10, 44, 100));
        modelsBox.setForeground(Color.decode("#8A7676"));
        modelsBox.setFont(new Font("Unispace", Font.BOLD, 20));
        ((JLabel)modelsBox.getRenderer()).setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        ((JLabel)modelsBox.getRenderer()).setFocusable(false);
//      ((JLabel)modelsBox.getRenderer()).setOpaque(false);
//      ((JLabel)modelsBox.getRenderer()).setBackground(new Color(18, 10, 44,100));

        info.addActionListener(EventsController.getInstance());
        info.setActionCommand(Actions.MAIN_INFO.name());
        add.addActionListener(EventsController.getInstance());
        add.setActionCommand(Actions.MAIN_ADD.name());
        recent.addActionListener(EventsController.getInstance());
        recent.setActionCommand(Actions.MAIN_RECENT.name());
        modelFilter.addActionListener(EventsController.getInstance());
        modelFilter.setActionCommand(Actions.MAIN_FILTER.name());

        infoPanel.add(info);
        infoPanel.setOpaque(false);
        addPanel.add(add);
        addPanel.setOpaque(false);
        recentPanel.add(recent);
        recentPanel.setOpaque(false);
        modelFilterPanel.add(modelsBox);
        modelFilterPanel.setOpaque(false);

        add(infoPanel);
        add(addPanel);
        add(recentPanel);
        add(modelFilterPanel);

    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        g.setColor( getBackground() );
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        super.paintComponent(g);
    }


///================================ MAIN RUNNER ============================

package test;

import java.awt.Image;

import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import views.CentralPanel;

public class TestViews extends JFrame {

    CentralPanel panel;

    public TestViews() {
        setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        panel = new CentralPanel();
        add(panel);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestViews();
    }
}

//================================ ENUM-COMBOBOX =============================

package models;

public enum EnumModels {


    NOVENTA("1990"),NOVENTA_UNO("1991"),NOVENTA_DOS("1992"),NOVENTA_TRES("1993"),NOVENTA_CUATRO("1994"),NOVENTA_CINCO("1995"),NOVENTA_SEIS("1996"),NOVENTA_SIETE("1997"),NOVENTA_OCHO("1998"),NOVENTA_NUEVE("1999"),
    DOSMIL_UNO("2001"),DOSMIL_DOS("2002"),DOSMIL_TRES("2003"),DOSMIL_CUATRO("2004"),DOSMIL_CINCO("2005"),DOSMIL_SEIS("2006"),DOSMIL_SIETE("2007"),DOSMIL_OCHO("2008"),DOSMIL_NUEVE("2009"),DOSMIL_DIEZ("2010"),DOSMIL_ONCE("2011"),
    DOSMIL_DOCE("2012"),DOSMIL_TRECE("2013"),DOSMIL_CATORCE("2014"),DOSMIL_QUINCE("2015"),DOSMIL_DIEZ_Y_SEIS("2016"),DOSMIL_DIEZ_Y_SIETE("2017"),DOSMIL_DIEZ_Y_OCHO("2018"),DOSMIL_DIEZ_Y_NUEVE("2019"),DOSMIL_VEINTE("2020");

    private String year;

    public String getYear() {
        return this.year;
    }

    private EnumModels(String year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return year;
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To help others answer your question better, consider creating a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which contains only what is needed to see the problem.

Comment: Still doesn't compile! Are the Actions relevant to the problem?  Is the controller rrelevant?. Are the MyButtons rrelevant? Are the enums relevant (you can just add Strings).  Are the Borders or Fonts relevant to the problem? Your question is about a combo box! Create a new project with a frame and a combo box that demonstrates the problem. If you can't simplify the problem, then you don't understand what you are asking. We don't NOT want to see your application, only the simplest piece of code that demonstrates the problem. The whole class with probably be about 20 lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

Swing components don't paint properly when you use transparent backgrounds because Swing expects the component to be opaque or non-opaque based on the setOpaque(...) property of the component.

If you want to use transparency, then you must manually make sure the background is painted with code something like:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel()
{
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        g.setColor( getBackground() );
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        super.paintComponent(g);
    }
};
panel.setOpaque(false); // background of parent will be painted first
panel.setBackground( new Color(255, 0, 0, 20) );
frame.add(panel);
```

You would need to customize the painting for each component using a transparent background.

Or a simpler approach is the use the `AlphaContainer`, which acts as a wrapper panel for a component and will paint the background for you. See [Backgrounds With Transparency](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/31/backgrounds-with-transparency/) for more information.

Comment: Yes, you're right i already did that over the component JComboBox. i created MyComboBoxClass and set it the paintComponent(), and then it stopped to get bugged. but the displayed items still have the problem just like in the link you sent me, thats exactly the bug, is there anyway to set that component to de JComboBox, as i tryied here :((JLabel)modelsBox.getRenderer()).setForeground(Color.red);
i mean, create MyLabel, set it the paintComponent() and the opaque false, and then add it to the JComboBox, instead its default JLabel where it shows its items..?

Comment: Probably because the combo popup displays over another component using a transparent background. You need the custom painting for all components using transparency. You still haven't posted an [mcve], so I can't offer further advice. Your question is about a frame a combo box, so create an example with only those components that demonstrated the problem, and shows how you implemented the suggestion given here.

Comment: i already edited it, there is an example of the transparency failure in the combobox items, you can run it and see how it looks, im sorry im kind of dummy for iu programming

Comment: `you can run` - no I can't because the code doesn't compile. You have code that is NOT related to the problem. Remove the code and make sure the code compiles. All you need is the frame and combo box to demonstrate the problem. All the other components are irrelevant to the problem and I don't have time to look at all that code.